# Java: Double with comma from String with unknown decimal separator

Tags: java

Starting from a String variable I need to obtain a Double value of it with comma as decimal separator.

I can't know if String will contains int numbers or number with decimals separated by dot or comma, so I need to catch cases of unappropriate String values as presence of chars or multiple dots or commas.

Comment: Replace  comma with `String.replace` then parse with `Double.parse`

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
String number = "20,981";
try {
    double dNumber = Double.parseDouble(number.replace(',', '.'));
    System.out.println("My double is " + dNumber);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    System.out.println("I got exception for invalid string " + number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `parseString()` or `valueOf()`. Surround your code with a try-catch-block to catch any NumberFormatExceptions. If you are unsure about whether your input String will contain a comma or a period, you may find the `replace()` useful (String class). Watch out, the first argument is a regular expression, so you need to escape the period!